# How can I get my HTML button to hide until called again? I have a clock with a button that needs to disappear when clicked or at a certain time

Tags: javascript, html, button, clock, filemaker

Endgoal: A digital clock that will display a button during a shift change for 7 minutes and changes the background color for that 7 minutes. Then at the 7 minute mark turns every thing back to the previous settings. And if you were to click the button it would perform a script in the application called "FileMaker Pro 19" and then hide the button.

Issue: I accomplished everything I wanted except the ability to have the button hide fully. It will hide for 1 second only because the displayClock() function is replay. I need a way for the script to know that the button has been pressed and will hide it for at least 7 minutes.

Code:

```
"data:text/html,

<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no' />

<html>

<head>

    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

        function displayClock() {
            var digital = new Date();
            var hours = digital.getHours();
            var minutes = digital.getMinutes();
            var seconds = digital.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';

            // Check if it is a weekday
            var isWeekday = (dayOfWeek !== 0 || dayOfWeek !== 6);

            // Get the current day of the week
            var dayOfWeek = digital.getDay();

            // Change the background color based on the time and day of the week
            if (isWeekday && hours == 14 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekday && hours == 14 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            } else if (isWeekday && hours == 22 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekday && hours == 22 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            } else if (isWeekday && hours == 6 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekday && hours == 6 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            }


            // Check if it is the weekend
            var isWeekend = (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6);

            // Change the background color based on the time and day of the week
            if (isWeekend && hours == 5 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekend && hours == 5 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            } else if (isWeekend && hours == 11 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekend && hours == 11 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            } else if (isWeekend && hours == 17 && minutes >= 0 && minutes < 7) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'block';
            } else if (isWeekend && hours == 17 && minutes > 6) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                document.body.style.color = 'black';
                document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
            }



            // Display the current time
            if (hours > 12) hours = hours - 12;
            if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
            if (minutes <= 9) minutes = '0' + minutes;
            if (seconds <= 9) seconds = '0' + seconds;
            dispTime = '<b>' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + '</b>';
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dispTime;

            // Call the function again after 1 second
            setTimeout('displayClock()', 1000);
        }

        function clockOut() {
            // Perform the FileMaker Script called 'Test230'
            FileMaker.PerformScript('Test230');
            document.getElementById('clockOutButton').style.display = 'none';
        }


    </script>
</head>

<body style='font-size:192;font-family:Arial;text-align:center; padding:0' onload='displayClock()'>

    <div id='time'></div>

    <p1 style='font-size:40;'></p1>


    <button id='clockOutButton'
        style='font-size: 20px; color: white; background-color: #B52025; padding: 10px 20px; border-radius: 5px;'
        onclick='clockOut()'>Clock Out</button>




</body>

</html>
"
```

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried using variables that get set when pressing the button. But being as I am not experienced with setTimeout functions it was always a struggle to get around those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you could fix this issue is by getting the time that the button is pressed, and comparing that value to the current time.
Date.getTime() is a useful fuction that will return the time in miliseconds that have passed from a fixed date. Therefore, you can compare the getTime() from when the button was pressed to the current getTime(). If the difference between the two times is greater than 7 minutes(420000 miliseconds), you will know that 7 minutes have passed, and can show the button again.
This would look something like:

```
function clockOut() {
    other code...
    lastPress = digital.getTime()
}
```

You could then compare it to the current time, which would look something like:

```
//check if 7 minutes has passed
if(digital.getTime()-lastPress>420000) {
   show element again...
}
```

Comment: Hope this helped!

Comment: It did help give me a new perspective on the issue. Would be possible for you to provide more detail. I'm a beginner when it comes to HTML and JavaScript. I may be placing things in the wrong spots or knowing my luck I forgot a semicolon somewhere.

Comment: Sure, what would you like to know more about?

Comment: On the "lastPress = digital.getTime()"  would I be placing "var" in front of that line or is that a valid function in JavaScript?

Comment: You would be declaring it at the top with your other variables. Example: var lastPress;

Comment: Sorry for the delayed responses (I work in IT and have Helpdesk stuff going on). I came close to getting it working I believe, I'll try to spend some time tomorrow reattempting. Is there any tips or suggestions you have for the placement of your suggestions in comparison to my functions and code? I believe my biggest issue at the moment is where I am placing some of this stuff. And a big thanks for responding to my post.

Comment: Declare var lastPress at the very top of your script, before all of your functions. This needs to be done in order to make the variable global, allowing both of your functions to access it. The rest of your code looks okay, but I would probably move the script to its own file if it gets too large.

Comment: You are a genius! It worked! I just had to set the lastPress variable as 420001 at the beginning so it had a value to start off with. Thanks for sticking with me through the steps.

Comment: No problem, it was my pleasure!